# JavaFX button.arm() not working. Are there other ways to?

Tags: button, javafx

I am trying to auto press a button in my application so that it triggers a function.

As per the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#arm%28%29), the `.arm()` button should do this. But it does not.

I also tried `.fire()`, but with no luck.

Any ideas on how to get a button be clicked on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[button.fire()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#fire%28%29) works and is the right method to use to trigger an automated button press.

Here is a short sample which demonstrates it's use:

[image: auto click]

A timeline is started which automatically fires a button every second.  When the button is fired it increments the counter label below the button.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Clicker extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label counter = new Label("0");

        Button clicker = new Button("Auto-clicked");
        clicker.setOnAction(event ->
            counter.setText(
                (1 + Integer.parseInt(counter.getText())) + ""
            )
        );

        Timeline ticker = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1), 
                event -> clicker.fire()
            )
        );
        ticker.setCycleCount(1_000_000);
        ticker.play();

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, clicker, counter);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Clicker.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jewelsea, i'll give this another try!